# C++: Can you return the value of a local variable from a static method?

Tags: c++, static

If i have something like this:

```
static const wchar_t* concatenate(const wchar_t* ws1, const wchar_t* ws2) {
    std::wstring s(ws1);
    s += std::wstring(ws2);
    return s.c_str();
}
```

It wouldn't work because the scope of 's' is within the static block, so the stack contents will be popped and the memory address to 's' is no longer valid, so my question is how can i do this?

Thanks

Comment: why don't you return `std::wstring` itself from the function?

Comment: The problem isn't that `s` is not longer valid (the assumption about it being invalid because it is "popped" from the stack is wrong). It is that `s` cleans up its internal state when the destructor is invoked (and thus the results of `c_str()` are invalid). At least one of the answers shows how to make a copy of `c_str()` data (which is then the callers responsibility to deal with).

Comment: returning wstring doesn't help, as pst pointed out the internal state of the string is cleared.

Comment: @Asim: If you return a `std::wstring`, then the internal state of `s` is no longer relevant once the function has returned; the value that was in `s` is **copied** into the return value, so it's no longer bound to a now-discarded stack frame. But you may be having problems if you call `c_str()` on the returned value, and then return from the calling method.

Comment: @Asim: returning a `wstring` surely helps, as it is the usual way of doing this. Moreover, using C-strings, converting them to `std` strings to finally convert them back to C-strings is really suboptimal and error prone.

Comment: @Dan, i understand what you are saying and that is how i expect it to behave but it is not. The wstring is returned but the underlying value gets reset.

Comment: @Asim, if you're seeing a problem after returning a `wstring`, it's almost certainly not due to the internal state of `s`. But to help you with it, we'd need to see both your current definition of `concatenate`, and the code where you're calling `concatenate` and using its returned value.

Comment: @Dan I realized that i had concatenate(..) as a static method of a class, that i was calling.

Comment: Just keep your strings in `std::wstring`. Never access the internal storage, unless you are interfacing with some C library.

Answer (score 12):

Change the function to return `std::wstring` instead of `wchar_t*`, and return `s`.

```
static std::wstring concatenate(const wchar_t* ws1, const wchar_t* ws2) {
    std::wstring s(ws1);
    s += std::wstring(ws2);
    return s;
}
```

By the way, this would be equally true for non-static methods.

Comment: @Asim: I'm not sure it's the same problem. What kind of error are you seeing now? (Are you calling `c_str()` on the returned value? In that case, yes, it's the same problem. Can you **avoid** calling `c_str()`, and simply use `std::wstring` everywhere? That would prevent problems like this from showing up again.)

Comment: @Asim, nope, it's returning by value - means that whatever you assign the return to, will receive a *copy* of what is in `s`. If this were to return a *reference*, that's a different issue (i.e. back to where you were)

Comment: Yes it is returning by value but the internal state is reset once the function returns.

Comment: @Asim, the internal state of `s` is **irrelevant** once the function returns. If you're still seeing a problem, it's probably because elsewhere in the program you're still using `c_str()`, and then returning from **that** stack frame.

Comment: @Nim - most if not all modern compilers will elide that copy using Named Return Value Optimization - this is the best way to solve the problem as OP stated it.

Answer (score 5):

The fact that the function is `static` is irrelevant here. You *could* return `s.c_str()` if the `s` *variable* was `static`, however this would be very weird as `s` would only initialized upon the first call of the function.

My recommendation : just return a `std::wstring` by value.

```
std::wstring concatenate(const wchar_t* ws1, const wchar_t* ws2) {
    std::wstring s(ws1);
    s += std::wstring(ws2);
    return s;
}
```

Comment: Also, be aware of the fact that the pointer returned by c_str() points to an area of memory used internally by s, and is only guaranteed to remain unchanged until the next call to a non-const member function on s.  Agree that returning by value is probably the best option, unless the interface can't change.

Comment: the initialization is not an issue really - given you can assign to it after! However it's not re-entrant which is it's main drawback...

Comment: @Nim: absolutely true, I expressed my answer this way because the OP seemed to be confused about `static`

Answer (score 2):

Replace your return statement with the following:

```
wchar_t *ret = new wchar_t[s.length()+1];
wcscpy(ret, s.c_str());
return ret;
```

The function as you wrote it doesn't work, because upon returning, the destructor for the local variable s is called, which frees the memory pointed to by s.c_str().

Comment: -1, because who is responsible for deleting that pointer?  We can assume the caller, but there's a huge chance for memory leaks here.  Sorry, but this is terrible.

Comment: @pst: But not the same interface contract: the caller must know to delete the returned string.

Comment: @Moo-Juice It is fine to preface this with a warning and best-practices. However, this answer meets the requirements of the question and provides more insight than a number of the other answers. In some cases "best" and "allowed" are not the same.

Comment: @Dan Breslau That confused me. What "contract" was altered?

Comment: @pst, warning programmers does not enforce them to follow that warning.  Whilst you are right that "best" != "allowed", it is better (in my humble opinion) to invoke discussion on "best".  There's plenty of things you're *allowed* to do in C++.  That doesn't mean you should ever do them.

Comment: @pst: By "interface contract", I mean the expected preconditions, behavior, and postconditions for the method. Examples of preconditions: the pointers ws1 and ws2 must not be `null`, and must point to null-terminated strings. Example of postconditions: the caller must delete the pointer that's returned by the method.

Comment: I understood the question to be along the lines of "how can I return my answer in a chunk of memory that will be valid outside of local scope?"  Agreed, doing it like this is not a good idea, but it answers the narrow question of how he can get his function to work as he wrote it.

Comment: @Kelsey, the function is a concatenation one which suggests to me he wants to put two strings together and get the result, and the answer to that is simple, return a `std::wstring`.  Granted, if the function allocated some kind of resource the story may well be different, but even then wrapping the return call in some kind of smart pointer would prevent the problem.

Comment: @Moo-Juice: If he knows enough to use std::wstring and write the function the way that he wrote it, then he (hopefully) knows that there's no need to write a concatenation function.  Granted, it might be a convenience method for cases where he's receiving wchar_t* from somewhere, but I get the impression that he really needs to have a pointer as output.  Why else go to the trouble to return c_str() as he tried to do?

Comment: @Kelsey, oh I agree 100%.  What he is doing doesn't make any sense at all.  I just think that newing memory and returning it all alone and naked, is a bad thing to do.  You know like, *Jesus executing kittens* bad.  :)

Comment: The question i asked was more to the point of how do i do this as the question itself suggests, not why do i do this. It was not a question on concatenation of 2 wchar_t, more an understanding. Instead the typical answer that i received was "always use std::wstring" and "don't call c_str()" but no one says why or backs it up with an example. Use wstring, fair enough, but you, i and the rest know that is not always going to be the case especially when you are passed down wchar_t or have to pass it to a 3rd party library.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the member function (we don't say "method" in C++) is `static` doesn't matter. You **can** return a local variable by value. What you **cannot** do is return a pointer or a reference to a local variable, or to a temporary value. `s.c_str()` creates a pointer either to temporary data or to part of the local `wstring`. So we cannot return that. Returning `s` (and adjusting the return type to match) is fine, because now we are returning by value, which (conceptually; it may be optimized) makes a copy of the local string on the stack in the return-value "slot".

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the function signature, try something like:

```
static const wchar_t* concatenate(const wchar_t* ws1, const wchar_t* ws2) {

    std::wstring s(ws1);
    wchar_t *r;

    s += std::wstring(ws2);

    /*
    * allocate the return value in heap (with room for the null termination)
    */
    r = new wchar_t[s.length() + 1]; 

    /*** copy ***/
    s.copy(r,s.length()+1);

    return r;
}
```

by the way (as said by others) you may return the entire s object,

Comment: -1, again, you're newing a pointer and returning it giving rise to the possibility of memory leaks.

Comment: I said "if you want to keep the function signature...". Of course that was not my favorite solution. By the way, in my opinion, dealing with pointers and memory allocation is fundamental for C++ developers: if a developer uses a 'pointed' object I think he knows that, sooner or later, that memory will have to be released.