# appending to std::string from char*

Tags: c++, string

I'm on `windows 8` and using `cygwin`, `g++`. I wrote a member function of my `Connection` class which is maintaining a connection and provides some operation to do with it. One of them is below:

```
 const char* Connection::recieve_all_data()
 {
      using namespace utils;
      if(socket_ == INVALID_SOCKET)
      {
             throw std::invalid_argument("Socket was not initialized\n");
      }

      std::string result = std::string();
      char *buf = new char[BUFFER_SIZE];
      while(true)
      {
               int iResult = recv(socket_, buf, utils::BUFFER_SIZE, 0);
               if(iResult == BUFFER_SIZE)
               {
                       result.append(buf);
                       std::cout << buf << std::endl << std::endl; //1, LOOK AT THIS LINE
               }
               else if (iResult < BUFFER_SIZE)
               {
                       char *final_buffer = new char[iResult + 1];
                       strncpy(final_buffer, buf, iResult);
                       final_buffer[iResult] = '\0';
                       result.append(final_buffer);
                       break;
               }
               else if(iResult == WSAENOTCONN)
               {
                       throw std::runtime_error("Socket was not connected");
               }
      }
      return result.c_str();
}
```

I tried to test that function to receive some data from `google.com`. And the thing is if line `//1` is not commented I receive the fulle respose asa follows:

```
HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 1419
Date: Wed, 25 Mar 2015 12:12:51 GMT
Server: GFE/2.0

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
  <title>Error 400 (Bad Request)!!1</title>
  <style>
    *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/logo_sm_2.png) no-repeat}@media only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/logo_sm_2_hr.png) no-repeat 0% 0%/100% 100%;-moz-border-image:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/logo_sm_2_hr.png) 0}}@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/logo_sm_2_hr.png) no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:100% 100%}}#logo{display:inline-block;height:55px;width:150px}
  </style>
  <a href=//www.google.com/><span id=logo aria-label=Google></span></a>
  <p><b>400.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins>
  <p>Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request.  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>
```

but if I comment line `//1` the recieved response is not full:

```
HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 1419
Date: Wed, 25 Mar 2015 12:12:07 GMT
Server: GFE/2.0

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
  <title>Error 400 (Bad Request)!!1</title>
  <style>
    *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/logo_sm_2.png) no-repeat}@media only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/logo_sm_2_hr.png) no-repeat 0% 0%/100% 100%;-moz-border-image:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/logo_sm_2_hr.png) 0}}@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/logo_sm_2_hr.png) no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:100% 100%}}#logo{display:inline-block;height:55px;width:150px}
  </style>
  <a href=
```

What's worng? I have really no idea about that behavior. How can the line `//1` ever affect the `result`? It's just an output. Maybe it's a `cygwin` problem?

Comment: Could it be that you're looking at the wrong data, i.e. not the *contents* of `result` returned by your function but the *output* of your function?

Comment: You've got a big problem, you are returning a `.c_str()` of a local variable that falls out of scope. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366586/c-can-you-return-the-value-of-a-local-variable-from-a-static-method This means your pointer is pointing at garbage after you leave the function.

Comment: @Cyber Don't see how  I could fix that?

Comment: Any chance you could change your function to return `std::string`? Then you could just `return result;`

Comment: @Cyber Yes, I could but it wouldn't be good. Maybe there is a solution without changing the return type...

Comment: `std::string result = std::string();` can be simplified to `std::string result;` and where do you delete `buf` or `final_buffer`?

Comment: Why would it not be good? You are programming in C++ and you are wrapping around a C-API. There is no reason not to adjust your wrapper to be C++-style.
If you HAVE to force a c-string return you will need to allocate a char* on the heap using the new operator and then copy your std::strings content into this c-string and then return this c-string.

Comment: I think you can forget `final_buffer` all you need to do is `result.append(buf, iResult);`.

Comment: @Galik Excellent note, I will take that into account.

Comment: Is buf 0-terminated? In general, it would not be, so it cannot be appended to the std::string.

Comment: Given that `buf` does not change size dynamically there is no need to dynamically allocate it. You can just do: `char buf[BUFFER_SIZE];`. That fixes one of your memory leaks too.

Comment: Also `std::string result = std::string();`. That looks like `Java`. In `C++` simply do `std::string result;`.

Comment: @Galik That is incase BUFFER_SIZE is a constant known at compile-time, you should mention that, other wise he will be back with a new question ( "My compiler says ... ").

Comment: Ugh. The memory leaks in that first function only slightly more-hideous than the assumption the data read is guaranteed to be null char terminated. The return value, as mentioned prior, is obviously bad.

Comment: @Galik It doesn't work for block scope variables.

Comment: @Galik Just `std::string result;` in block scope will result in indeterminate value. Actually, 8.5.12 standard _if no initialization is performed, an object with automatic or dynamic storage duration has indeterminate value_

Comment: @user3663882 `8.5.2` is talking about arrays of char not `std::string`. A `std::string` is a user defined type and so it will be default constructed as empty.

Comment: @Galik Yes, 8.5.2 is talking about arrays of chars, but I was talking about 8.5.12 section.

Comment: @user3663882 Standard says: **8.5.9** *"If no initializer is specified for an object, and the object is of (possibly cv-qualified) non-POD class type (or array thereof), the object shall be default-initialized;"*

Comment: @Galik No, 8.5/9 of N4296 doesn't say that. But, look at 8.5/12 _If no initializer is specified for an object, the object is default-initialized. When storage for an object with **automatic** or dynamic storage duration is obtained, the object has an indeterminate value_

Comment: @Galik What version of the stadnard are you using, BTW?

Comment: I was looking at 2003 & 2011 not 2014! It says the object will be "default initialized" and that auto storage won't be zero-initialized which means its down to the constructor to give its members meaningful values. But it will always be "default constructed".